# remove file names completely from url with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

With some modifications is possible to hide extension of the web files like http://www.abc.com/asd/zxc/ against to zxc.php but the thing I wanna do is remove file names completely from the url like `http://www.abc.com/asd/` it doesn't matter user where to go in web site but the url should be stay static all the time.

Is it possible to do that with `.htaccess`?

I already tried this but it didn't work:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On  # enables url rewriting

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  # if requested uri is not directory (!-d)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f # and if there is a file named URI+'.php' (-f)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php # then if there is any thing in uri then rewrite it as uri+'.php'
```

Comment: I updated my answer and now I've tested it to check that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but isn't the problem that you would like to check so the supplied url fragment is not a directory **and** not a file, and if that's the case, append `.php` to the fragment?

Something like this might work:

```
RewriteEngine On                    # enable mod_rewrite 
RewriteBase /                       # set the 'base' for the rewrite
                                    # you might need to modify this one.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a directory
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1\.php [L]     # append '.php' to the path
                                    #
```

If you have the following directory structure, and of course the `.htaccess` file in the root of the structure:

```
/code/test.php
/index.php
```

You should be able to access the `test.php` and `index.php` files by using the following urls:

`http://example.com/code/test/`

and

`http://example.com/index/`

The `example.com` needs to be change to a valid domain or ip address.

Comment: this returns "Internal Server Error", my url like "http://192.168.2.254/showcalendar/index.php" and the pages like "http://192.168.2.254/showcalendar/SubRouter.php" is it possible to keep url like "http://192.168.2.254/showcalendar/" all the time ?

Comment: Have you tested the updated code above, I tried it on my server and it works fine. Do you have `mod_rewrite` enabled? Try setting the `RewriteBase` to you directory like `RewriteBase /testfolder`. Have you put the `.htaccess` file in the correct folder?

Comment: thanks for your answer the strange thing is it works on my pc's apache server but when i try on my Qnap NAS it returns 500 Internal Server Error. I think i have to check out the Qnap forums. Thanks again.

Comment: @Sheshman - Did you solved the problem on your NAS? Would be interesting to know what went wrong?